# cython magic cannot find include file when it is in the same directory

Tags: compilation, ipython, cython, cblas

[image: error pic]

I am getting this error upon running the following code block in ipython:

```
%%cython
cdef extern from "cblas.h":
    enum CBLAS_ORDER:
        CblasRowMajor=101
        CblasColMajor=102
    enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE:
        CblasNoTrans=111
        CblasTrans=112
        CblasConjTrans=113
        AtlasConj=114
```

It says "Cannot open include file "cblas.h": No such file or directory"
when cblas.h is in the same folder as the ipython notebook. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cython failed with exit status 2 when trying to access library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390860/cython-failed-with-exit-status-2-when-trying-to-access-library)

Comment: Please don't repeatedly ask the same question. You can edit your existing question to clarify (as you have done)